# Dynamically Add Elements to jQuery Sortable

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

This should be my last question on Jquery Sortable...for a while :)

I have a list that I'm able to remove elements from dynamically.  when users click the X close box on the element, I get the parent (the element itself) and remove it:

```
    function DeleteLink() {
        var jItem = $(this).parent();

        var LinkId = jItem[0].childNodes[1].innerText || jItem[0].childNodes[3].textContent;
        var LinkTitle = jItem[0].childNodes[2].innerText || jItem[0].childNodes[5].textContent;

        if (!confirm(String.format("Are you sure you want to delete link #{0}?\n\nTitle: {1}", LinkId, LinkTitle)))
            return;

        jItem.remove();
        $.post("/Home/DeleteLink/" + LinkId);
        showStatus("Link deleted...", 5000);
    }
```

If you are interested, unordered list is created like this:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
        <% foreach (Link l in Model)
             {
                 if (l.Visible == true)
                 {%>
                    <li class="photolistitem" style="min-height:50px;">
                    <div class="imagecontainer"><img src="/Content/images/link.jpg" style="float:left; padding-right:5px;" class="thumbnailimage" alt="" /></div>
                    <div id='<%=l.Id%>Id'><%=l.Id%></div>
                    <div id='<%=l.Id%>Description'><%=l.Title%></div>
                    <div id='<%=l.Id%>Description'><%=l.Description%></div>
                    <div id='<%=l.Id%>Description'><%=l.Url%></div>
                    <div class='deletethumbnail'>X</div>
                    </li>
               <%}%>
       <%}%>  
    </ul>
```

What I want to do is to have a form on the bottom of the page so that a user can add an element dynamically - They will only need to insert a description, a title, and a url (I will use another jquery plugin to validate the input).

I think the biggest challenge will be dynamically creating an object that can be appended to the list.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery

```
thisDependant = $('.DependantTemplate').clone();
$(thisDependant).removeClass("DependantTemplate");
$(thisDependant).addClass("Dependant" + dependantNum);
$('.DependantList').append(thisDependant);
```

HTML

```
<div class="DependantTemplate hidden">
  <div style="float:left;" class="DependantNumber spacerRight10"></div>
  <div style="float:left;" class="DependantFirstName spacerRight10"></div>
  <div style="float:left;" class="DependantLastName spacerRight10"></div>
  <div style="float:left;" class="DependantDateOfBirth spacerRight10"></div>
  <div style="float:left;" class="DependantGender spacerRight10"></div>
  <div style="float:left;" class="DependantType"></div>
  <div class="clearFloats"></div>
</div>

<div class="DependantList"></div>
```

The above is what I use to do the same as you're looking for.

Comment: That's perfect, and much less painful that I had imagined.  Thank you!